# ASP.NET MVC 4, Windows Authentication and Active Directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory, windows-authentication

I have two machines:

1. Windows 2008 - for Active Directory
2. Windows 7 - installed with IIS7, it also serves as development machine. Note that this PC is not member of the domain.

I tried Forms Authentication and it's working fine with this configuration in my web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ADConn" connectionString="LDAP://192.168.0.21" />
</connectionStrings>

<membership defaultProvider="ADMembership">
  <providers>
    <add name="ADMembership"
         type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider"
         connectionStringName="ADConn"
         connectionUsername="dominic"
         attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"
         connectionPassword="p@ssw0rd" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Now I want to change from Form to Windows Authentication. My questions are:

1. What configurations do I need to add in Web.Config to enable Windows Authentication?
2. What configurations should be done in IIS to enable Windows Authentication?
3. Do I need to configure Windows Firewall?
4. When logging in using Windows Authentication, what should be my username? Is it "192.168.0.21\dominic" or "dominic"?
5. Did I miss to ask any question?

I tried many tutorials today but it's either giving me 403 or it's not accepting my username and password. If you know any complete step-by-step tutorial, please let me know.

Comment: I think you might struggle to get Windows Authentication working on a machine that is off the domain. Is this a Web or Intranet app?

Comment: Intranet... What would be the problem if the PC is not in a domain?

Comment: I stand corrected it should make no difference. Full details are here http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication

Comment: Thanks. Ill read it later. I should have used IIS as keyword when I was searching.

Answer (score 2):

After days of research, it turns out that IIS at least, should be a member of the domain. The client does not necessarily be a member of the domain.

In the Web.Config, all I need to add is:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <allow users="*"/>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Connection string and membership are not necessary.